# format string error in c#

Tags: c#

The following line gives an error:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Order:{0},\n Placed:{1},\nshipped:{2},\nTo address:{3} ,{4}, {5}\n\n" + orderid, orderdate, shipdate, shipname, shipaddr, shipcity);
```

It shows an error as:

> (Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero an d less than the size of the argument list.)

Help me out to resolve this error. I know this error happened because of the place holder provided are greater than the variables provided.

Comment: Check your syntax... you put a '+' instead a ',' to provide 6 arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Order:{0},\n Placed:{1},\nshipped:{2},\nTo address:{3} ,{4}, {5}\n\n",orderid, orderdate, shipdate, shipname, shipaddr, shipcity);
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: Actually ryadavilli was the first to answer.

Comment: Thanks Peter Huene. What matters most to me is that Gomathipriya has found answer to the query. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you wanted:

```
Console.WriteLine("Order:{0},\n Placed:{1},\nshipped:{2},\nTo address:{3} ,{4}, {5}\n\n", orderid, orderdate, shipdate, shipname, shipaddr, shipcity);
```

Note the + is not present.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `+` instead of a `,` before your first argument.  Correction:

```
Console.WriteLine("Order:{0},\n Placed:{1},\nshipped:{2},\nTo address:{3} ,{4}, {5}\n\n", orderid, orderdate, shipdate, shipname, shipaddr, shipcity);
```

The method is therefore only recognising 5 parameters, not 6.

Comment: I think you mean "The method is therefore only recognising 5 parameters, not 6."

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a plus at the end of your format string ? This is causing the params to be 5 when the format string expects 6.

Change as below :

```
Console.WriteLine("Order:{0},\n Placed:{1},\nshipped:{2},\nTo address:{3} ,{4}, {5}\n\n", orderid, orderdate, shipdate, shipname, shipaddr, shipcity);
```